# Div 100% width minus an images width

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a mobile html5 site.

http://jsfiddle.net/ko7o8kkd/

What do i need to do that the green part defined by...

```
<div class="toplevelpadding searchbar">
```

... takes as much width as it can, But the search icon to the right is still on the same line?

Basically, it should have width=100%-(iconwidth + somepadding).

How is this achieved the best? It should be as cross browser as possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the width of the icon and padding is static you could use the calc method of css3

Say icon = 50px and total padding is 20px;

```
/* Firefox */
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 70px);
/* WebKit */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 70px);
/* Opera */
    width: -o-calc(100% - 70px);
/* Standard */
    width: calc(100% - 70px);
```

Comment: If you check canIuse, the vendor prefixes fo `calc()` aren't necessary : http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Well I would like to do this without having to specify the images' width. I thought there were any other way?

Comment: Do you have something like PHP/ASP/Angular with the page?